# Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components

Tags: reactjs, material-table

React keeps giving me this "Warning" (which registers as an error in the console) whenever I click on the edit row section of the material table. I understand the Warning is happening because there are some parameters of the table that are left undefined and therefore being logged as null. I am wondering how can I avoid this situation please see the code below. My components are uncontrolled as the user can type in the columns of a particular row of material table.

```
data={props.devices}
                editable={{
                    onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                                let newArr = [...props.devices];
                                newArr[index] = newData;
                                
                                setParts(newArr);
                                updatePart(newData, newData.device);
                                resolve();
                            }, 1000);
                        }),
```

Here is the full error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
    in input (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in ForwardRef(InputBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)) (created by ForwardRef(Input))
    in ForwardRef(Input) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Input)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Input)) (created by ForwardRef(TextField))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(FormControl))
    in ForwardRef(FormControl) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(FormControl)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(FormControl)) (created by ForwardRef(TextField))
    in ForwardRef(TextField) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField)) (created by MTableEditField)
    in MTableEditField (created by MTableEditRow)
    in td (created by ForwardRef(TableCell))
    in ForwardRef(TableCell) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)) (created by MTableEditRow)
    in tr (created by ForwardRef(TableRow))
    in ForwardRef(TableRow) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)) (created by MTableEditRow)
    in MTableEditRow (created by MTableBody)
    in tbody (created by ForwardRef(TableBody))
    in ForwardRef(TableBody) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)) (created by MTableBody)
    in MTableBody (created by Droppable)
    in table (created by ForwardRef(Table))
    in ForwardRef(Table) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)) (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in Droppable (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction
    in ConnectFunction (created by MaterialTable)
    in div
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (created by MaterialTable)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Container)
    in Container (created by MaterialTable)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by ErrorBoundary)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by DragDropContext)
    in DragDropContext (created by MaterialTable)
    in MaterialTable
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that's creating `<input value={x} />`? The warning is saying the value `null` is being passed to the input.

Comment: I do not have <input /> this is a material table being edited. I will update the full error above.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. Did you fix it @AS.?

Answer (score 0):

why are you using setTimeOut?
the mui table receives null at first render, so just remove setTimeOut.
and make sure no value is null, if its null replace it with empty string "".